# Weird performance problem when using EXISTS

Tags: sql, oracle, oracle11g, query-optimization

I improved my SELECT by replacing LEFT JOINs and ORs with EXISTS:

[image]

The problem is that original SELECT took 700 ms but new changed SELECT takes 35+ minutes to execute (and still counting). This is crazy. Does anyone has any explanation for it? How can I find what is causing this performance issue? It looks like some kind of the never ending loop...?

Old SELECT:

```
SELECT pcl.COL1,
       pcl.COL2,
       pcl.COL3,
       pcl.COL4,
       (SELECT cc.COL5
          FROM T3 cc
          JOIN T4 cvp
            ON cvp.COL10 = cc.COL10
           AND cvp.COL2 = pcl.COL2) AS COL10,
       pp.COL11
FROM T1 ba
JOIN T2 pcl
  ON pcl.COL1 = ba.COL1
 AND (pcl.COL2 = ba.COL2 OR ba.COL2 = 0)
JOIN T5 pscl
  ON pscl.COL2 = pcl.COL2
 AND pscl.COL4 <> 3
 AND (pscl.COL6 = ba.COL6 OR ba.COL6 = 'ALL')
LEFT JOIN T6 bba
  ON bba.COL7 = ba.COL7
LEFT JOIN T7 bsa
  ON bsa.COL7 = ba.COL7
LEFT JOIN T8 pp
  ON pp.COL1 = pcl.COL1
WHERE (ba.COL8 = 617617 OR bsa.COL8 = 617617 OR bba.COL9 = 617617)
 AND ba.COL4 <> 3
 AND pcl.COL4 <> 3
 AND pscl.COL4 <> 3
 AND NOT EXISTS
(SELECT *
       FROM T1 ba2
      WHERE ba2.COL1 = ba.COL1
        AND ((ba2.COL2 = pcl.COL2 AND
            (ba2.COL6 = pscl.COL6 OR ba2.COL6 = 'ALL')) OR
            (ba.COL6 = 'ALL' AND ba.COL2 = 0 AND ba2.COL6 = pscl.COL6))
        AND (ba2.COL2 <> ba.COL2 OR ba2.COL2 = 0)
        AND ba2.COL13 = ba.COL13
        AND ba2.COL12 = ba.COL12
        AND ba2.COL4 <> 3)
UNION (SELECT pcl.COL1,
           pcl.COL2,
           pcl.COL3,
           pcl.COL4,
           (SELECT cc.COL5
              FROM T3 cc
              JOIN T4 cvp
                ON cvp.COL10 = cc.COL10
               AND cvp.COL2 = pcl.COL2) AS COL10,
           pp.COL11
      FROM T9 sa
      LEFT JOIN T2 pcl
        on sa.COL1 = pcl.COL1
       and (sa.COL2 = pcl.COL2 or sa.COL2 = 0)
       and (sa.COL14 = pcl.COL14)
       and pcl.COL4 <> 6
       and pcl.COL4 is not null
       AND pcl.COL3 is not null
      LEFT JOIN T8 pp
        on pp.COL1 = pcl.COL1
     WHERE sa.COL8 = 617617
       AND pcl.COL14 = 100805)
ORDER BY COL11, COL1, COL4, COL3;
```

New SELECT:

```
 SELECT pcl.COL1,
        pcl.COL2,
        pcl.COL3,
        pcl.COL4,
        (SELECT cc.COL5
           FROM T3 cc
           JOIN T4 cvp
             ON cvp.COL10 = cc.COL10
            AND cvp.COL2 = pcl.COL2) AS COL10,
        pp.COL11
   FROM T1 ba
   JOIN T2 pcl
     ON pcl.COL1 = ba.COL1
    AND (pcl.COL2 = ba.COL2 OR ba.COL2 = 0)
   JOIN T5 pscl
     ON pscl.COL2 = pcl.COL2
    AND pscl.COL4 <> 3
    AND (pscl.COL6 = ba.COL6 OR
        ba.COL6 = 'ALL')
   LEFT JOIN T8 pp
     ON pp.COL1 = pcl.COL1
  WHERE ba.COL8 = 617617
        OR EXISTS(SELECT 1 FROM T6 bba WHERE bba.COL7 = ba.COL7 AND bba.COL9 = 617617)
        OR EXISTS(SELECT 1 FROM T7 bsa WHERE bsa.COL7 = ba.COL7 AND bsa.COL8 = 617617)
    AND ba.COL4 <> 3
    AND pcl.COL4 <> 3
    AND pscl.COL4 <> 3
    AND NOT EXISTS
  (SELECT *
           FROM T1 ba2
          WHERE ba2.COL1 = ba.COL1
            AND ((ba2.COL2 = pcl.COL2 AND
                (ba2.COL6 = pscl.COL6 OR
                ba2.COL6 = 'ALL')) OR
                (ba.COL6 = 'ALL' AND
                ba.COL2 = 0 AND
                ba2.COL6 = pscl.COL6))
            AND (ba2.COL2 <> ba.COL2 OR
                ba2.COL2 = 0)
            AND ba2.COL13 = ba.COL13
            AND ba2.COL12 = ba.COL12
            AND ba2.COL4 <> 3
            )
 UNION (SELECT pcl.COL1,
               pcl.COL2,
               pcl.COL3,
               pcl.COL4,
               (SELECT cc.COL5
                  FROM T3 cc
                  JOIN T4 cvp
                    ON cvp.COL10 = cc.COL10
                   AND cvp.COL2 = pcl.COL2) AS COL10,
               pp.COL11
          FROM T9 sa
          LEFT JOIN T2 pcl
            on sa.COL1 = pcl.COL1
           and (sa.COL2 = pcl.COL2 or
               sa.COL2 = 0)
           and (sa.COL14 = pcl.COL14)
           and pcl.COL4 <> 6
           and pcl.COL4 is not null
           AND pcl.COL3 is not null
          LEFT JOIN T8 pp
            on pp.COL1 = pcl.COL1
         WHERE sa.COL8 = 617617
           AND pcl.COL14 = 100805)
  ORDER BY COL11, COL1, COL4, COL3;
```

Old execution plan:

```
-----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
| Id  | Operation                               | Name                                   | Starts | E-Rows | A-Rows |   A-Time   | Buffers |  OMem |  1Mem |  O/1/M   |
-----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
|   0 | SELECT STATEMENT                        |                                        |      1 |        |      1 |00:00:00.89 |   64899 |       |       |          |
|   1 |  SORT UNIQUE                            |                                        |      1 |   4136K|      1 |00:00:00.89 |   64899 |  2048 |  2048 |     1/0/0|
|   2 |   UNION-ALL                             |                                        |      1 |        |     27 |00:00:00.71 |   64899 |       |       |          |
|   3 |    NESTED LOOPS                         |                                        |      1 |      1 |      1 |00:00:00.01 |       7 |       |       |          |
|   4 |     TABLE ACCESS BY INDEX ROWID         | T4                                     |      1 |      1 |      1 |00:00:00.01 |       5 |       |       |          |
|*  5 |      INDEX UNIQUE SCAN                  | I_PK_VPCCONT                           |      1 |      1 |      1 |00:00:00.01 |       3 |       |       |          |
|   6 |     TABLE ACCESS BY INDEX ROWID         | T3                                     |      1 |      1 |      1 |00:00:00.01 |       2 |       |       |          |
|*  7 |      INDEX UNIQUE SCAN                  | I_PK_SYSCONCA                          |      1 |      1 |      1 |00:00:00.01 |       1 |       |       |          |
|*  8 |    FILTER                               |                                        |      1 |        |     27 |00:00:00.71 |   64888 |       |       |          |
|   9 |     NESTED LOOPS                        |                                        |      1 |   5940K|     27 |00:00:00.71 |   64885 |       |       |          |
|  10 |      NESTED LOOPS                       |                                        |      1 |   5940K|     81 |00:00:00.71 |   64861 |       |       |          |
|  11 |       NESTED LOOPS OUTER                |                                        |      1 |   7702 |      1 |00:00:00.89 |   64857 |       |       |          |
|* 12 |        HASH JOIN                        |                                        |      1 |   7702 |      1 |00:00:00.89 |   64853 |   962K|   962K|     1/0/0|
|* 13 |         FILTER                          |                                        |      1 |        |      1 |00:00:00.25 |   38012 |       |       |          |
|* 14 |          HASH JOIN RIGHT OUTER          |                                        |      1 |  16426 |   1645K|00:00:00.84 |   38012 |  2920K|  2920K|     1/0/0|
|  15 |           VIEW                          | index$_join$_011                       |      1 |      1 |      0 |00:00:00.01 |       4 |       |       |          |
|* 16 |            HASH JOIN                    |                                        |      1 |        |      0 |00:00:00.01 |       4 |  2078K|  2078K|     1/0/0|
|  17 |             INDEX FAST FULL SCAN        | I_FK_BUSTLACC_SETTACC_COL8             |      1 |      1 |      0 |00:00:00.01 |       4 |       |       |          |
|  18 |             INDEX FAST FULL SCAN        | I_UK_BUSTLACC_COL7_AMOUNTTYPE          |      0 |      1 |      0 |00:00:00.01 |       0 |       |       |          |
|* 19 |           HASH JOIN RIGHT OUTER         |                                        |      1 |   1641K|   1645K|00:00:00.54 |   38008 |    24M|  4789K|     1/0/0|
|  20 |            TABLE ACCESS FULL            | T6                                     |      1 |    414K|    413K|00:00:00.01 |    1634 |       |       |          |
|* 21 |            TABLE ACCESS FULL            | T1                                     |      1 |   1632K|   1636K|00:00:00.28 |   36374 |       |       |          |
|* 22 |         TABLE ACCESS FULL               | T2                                     |      1 |   1100K|   1102K|00:00:00.16 |   26841 |       |       |          |
|  23 |        TABLE ACCESS BY INDEX ROWID      | T8                                     |      1 |      1 |      1 |00:00:00.01 |       4 |       |       |          |
|* 24 |         INDEX UNIQUE SCAN               | I_PK_PARTNER                           |      1 |      1 |      1 |00:00:00.01 |       3 |       |       |          |
|* 25 |       INDEX RANGE SCAN                  | I_FK_PCSUBLIN_CONTRACT_COL2            |      1 |      8 |     81 |00:00:00.01 |       4 |       |       |          |
|* 26 |      TABLE ACCESS BY INDEX ROWID        | T5                                     |     81 |    771 |     27 |00:00:00.01 |      24 |       |       |          |
|* 27 |     TABLE ACCESS BY INDEX ROWID BATCHED | T1                                     |      1 |      1 |      0 |00:00:00.01 |       3 |       |       |          |
|* 28 |      INDEX RANGE SCAN                   | I_BUSIACC_COL1_3C                      |      1 |      1 |      0 |00:00:00.01 |       3 |       |       |          |
|  29 |    NESTED LOOPS                         |                                        |      0 |      1 |      0 |00:00:00.01 |       0 |       |       |          |
|  30 |     TABLE ACCESS BY INDEX ROWID         | T4                                     |      0 |      1 |      0 |00:00:00.01 |       0 |       |       |          |
|* 31 |      INDEX UNIQUE SCAN                  | I_PK_VPCCONT                           |      0 |      1 |      0 |00:00:00.01 |       0 |       |       |          |
|  32 |     TABLE ACCESS BY INDEX ROWID         | T3                                     |      0 |      1 |      0 |00:00:00.01 |       0 |       |       |          |
|* 33 |      INDEX UNIQUE SCAN                  | I_PK_SYSCONCA                          |      0 |      1 |      0 |00:00:00.01 |       0 |       |       |          |
|  34 |    NESTED LOOPS OUTER                   |                                        |      1 |      1 |      0 |00:00:00.01 |       4 |       |       |          |
|  35 |     NESTED LOOPS                        |                                        |      1 |      1 |      0 |00:00:00.01 |       4 |       |       |          |
|* 36 |      TABLE ACCESS BY INDEX ROWID        | T9                                     |      1 |      1 |      0 |00:00:00.01 |       4 |       |       |          |
|* 37 |       INDEX UNIQUE SCAN                 | I_PK_SETTACC                           |      1 |      1 |      1 |00:00:00.01 |       3 |       |       |          |
|* 38 |      TABLE ACCESS BY INDEX ROWID BATCHED| T2                                     |      0 |      1 |      0 |00:00:00.01 |       0 |       |       |          |
|* 39 |       INDEX RANGE SCAN                  | I_PARCONLI_PID_PARTNERMCC              |      0 |      1 |      0 |00:00:00.01 |       0 |       |       |          |
|  40 |     TABLE ACCESS BY INDEX ROWID         | T8                                     |      0 |      1 |      0 |00:00:00.01 |       0 |       |       |          |
|* 41 |      INDEX UNIQUE SCAN                  | I_PK_PARTNER                           |      0 |      1 |      0 |00:00:00.01 |       0 |       |       |          |
-----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
 
Predicate Information (identified by operation id):
---------------------------------------------------
 
   5 - access("CVP"."COL2"=:B1)
   7 - access("CVP"."COL10"="CC"."COL10")
   8 - filter( IS NULL)
  12 - access("PCL"."COL1"="BA"."COL1")
       filter(("PCL"."COL2"="BA"."COL2" OR "BA"."COL2"=0))
  13 - filter(("BA"."COL8"=617617 OR "BSA"."COL8"=617617 OR "BBA"."COL9"=617617))
  14 - access("BSA"."COL7"="BA"."COL7")
  16 - access(ROWID=ROWID)
  19 - access("BBA"."COL7"="BA"."COL7")
  21 - filter("BA"."COL4"<>3)
  22 - filter("PCL"."COL4"<>3)
  24 - access("PP"."COL1"="PCL"."COL1")
  25 - access("PSCL"."COL2"="PCL"."COL2")
  26 - filter(("PSCL"."COL4"<>3 AND ("PSCL"."COL6"="BA"."COL6" OR "BA"."COL6"='ALL')))
  27 - filter(("BA2"."COL12"=:B1 AND "BA2"."COL13"=:B2 AND "BA2"."COL4"<>3))
  28 - access("BA2"."COL1"=:B1)
       filter((((:B1='ALL' AND :B2=0 AND "BA2"."COL6"=:B3) OR ("BA2"."COL2"=:B4 AND INTERNAL_FUNCTION("BA2"."COL6"))) AND 
              ("BA2"."COL2"<>:B5 OR "BA2"."COL2"=0)))
  31 - access("CVP"."COL2"=:B1)
  33 - access("CVP"."COL10"="CC"."COL10")
  36 - filter("SA"."COL14"=100805)
  37 - access("SA"."COL8"=617617)
  38 - filter(("PCL"."COL14"=100805 AND ("SA"."COL2"="PCL"."COL2" OR "SA"."COL2"=0) AND "PCL"."COL4"<>6))
  39 - access("SA"."COL1"="PCL"."COL1")
  41 - access("PP"."COL1"="PCL"."COL1")
```

New execution plan:

```
Plan hash value: 3990748374
 
-----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
| Id  | Operation                               | Name                                  | Rows  | Bytes |TempSpc| Cost (%CPU)| Time     |
-----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
|   0 | SELECT STATEMENT                        |                                       |    50M|  4884M|       |  2162K  (1)| 00:01:25 |
|   1 |  SORT UNIQUE                            |                                       |    50M|  4884M|    10G|  1268K  (1)| 00:00:50 |
|   2 |   UNION-ALL                             |                                       |       |       |       |            |          |
|   3 |    NESTED LOOPS                         |                                       |     1 |    28 |       |     2   (0)| 00:00:01 |
|   4 |     TABLE ACCESS BY INDEX ROWID         | T4                                    |     1 |     9 |       |     1   (0)| 00:00:01 |
|*  5 |      INDEX UNIQUE SCAN                  | I_PK_VPCCONT                          |     1 |       |       |     1   (0)| 00:00:01 |
|   6 |     TABLE ACCESS BY INDEX ROWID         | T3                                    |     1 |    19 |       |     1   (0)| 00:00:01 |
|*  7 |      INDEX UNIQUE SCAN                  | I_PK_SYSCONCA                         |     1 |       |       |     1   (0)| 00:00:01 |
|*  8 |    FILTER                               |                                       |       |       |       |            |          |
|*  9 |     HASH JOIN                           |                                       |   979M|    93G|   119M| 98927   (8)| 00:00:04 |
|* 10 |      HASH JOIN RIGHT OUTER              |                                       |  1269K|   105M|    49M| 48138   (1)| 00:00:02 |
|  11 |       TABLE ACCESS FULL                 | T8                                    |  1353K|    33M|       | 16120   (1)| 00:00:01 |
|* 12 |       HASH JOIN                         |                                       |  1269K|    73M|    52M| 25182   (1)| 00:00:01 |
|  13 |        TABLE ACCESS FULL                | T2                                    |  1488K|    35M|       |  7510   (1)| 00:00:01 |
|  14 |        TABLE ACCESS FULL                | T1                                    |  2232K|    76M|       |  9964   (1)| 00:00:01 |
|* 15 |      TABLE ACCESS FULL                  | T5                                    |  5413K|    77M|       | 30731   (1)| 00:00:02 |
|* 16 |     TABLE ACCESS BY INDEX ROWID BATCHED | T6                                    |     1 |    12 |       |     1   (0)| 00:00:01 |
|* 17 |      INDEX SKIP SCAN                    | I_UK_BUBIACC_BUSIACCNO_CONDCOD        |     1 |       |       |     1   (0)| 00:00:01 |
|* 18 |     TABLE ACCESS BY INDEX ROWID BATCHED | T7                                    |     1 |    26 |       |     1   (0)| 00:00:01 |
|* 19 |      INDEX RANGE SCAN                   | I_FK_BUSTLACC_SETTACC_COL8            |     1 |       |       |     1   (0)| 00:00:01 |
|* 20 |     TABLE ACCESS BY INDEX ROWID BATCHED | T1                                    |     1 |    24 |       |     1   (0)| 00:00:01 |
|* 21 |      INDEX RANGE SCAN                   | I_BUSIACC_COL1_3C                     |     1 |       |       |     1   (0)| 00:00:01 |
|  22 |    NESTED LOOPS                         |                                       |     1 |    28 |       |     2   (0)| 00:00:01 |
|  23 |     TABLE ACCESS BY INDEX ROWID         | T4                                    |     1 |     9 |       |     1   (0)| 00:00:01 |
|* 24 |      INDEX UNIQUE SCAN                  | I_PK_VPCCONT                          |     1 |       |       |     1   (0)| 00:00:01 |
|  25 |     TABLE ACCESS BY INDEX ROWID         | T3                                    |     1 |    19 |       |     1   (0)| 00:00:01 |
|* 26 |      INDEX UNIQUE SCAN                  | I_PK_SYSCONCA                         |     1 |       |       |     1   (0)| 00:00:01 |
|  27 |    NESTED LOOPS OUTER                   |                                       |     1 |    76 |       |     3   (0)| 00:00:01 |
|  28 |     NESTED LOOPS                        |                                       |     1 |    50 |       |     2   (0)| 00:00:01 |
|* 29 |      TABLE ACCESS BY INDEX ROWID        | T9                                    |     1 |    20 |       |     1   (0)| 00:00:01 |
|* 30 |       INDEX UNIQUE SCAN                 | I_PK_SETTACC                          |     1 |       |       |     1   (0)| 00:00:01 |
|* 31 |      TABLE ACCESS BY INDEX ROWID BATCHED| T2                                    |     1 |    30 |       |     1   (0)| 00:00:01 |
|* 32 |       INDEX RANGE SCAN                  | I_PARCONLI_PID_PARTNERMCC             |     1 |       |       |     1   (0)| 00:00:01 |
|  33 |     TABLE ACCESS BY INDEX ROWID         | T8                                    |     1 |    26 |       |     1   (0)| 00:00:01 |
|* 34 |      INDEX UNIQUE SCAN                  | I_PK_PARTNER                          |     1 |       |       |     1   (0)| 00:00:01 |
-----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
 
Predicate Information (identified by operation id):
---------------------------------------------------
 
   5 - access("CVP"."COL2"=:B1)
   7 - access("CVP"."COL10"="CC"."COL10")
   8 - filter("BA"."COL8"=617617 OR  EXISTS (SELECT 0 FROM "IPASS_PROD"."T6" "BBA" WHERE 
              "BBA"."COL7"=:B1 AND "BBA"."COL9"=617617) OR "BA"."COL4"<>3 AND "PCL"."COL4"<>3 AND  
              EXISTS (SELECT 0 FROM "IPASS_PROD"."T7" "BSA" WHERE "BSA"."COL8"=617617 AND 
              "BSA"."COL7"=:B2) AND  NOT EXISTS (SELECT 0 FROM "IPASS_PROD"."T1" "BA2" WHERE "BA2"."COL1"=:B3 AND 
              "BA2"."COL12"=:B4 AND "BA2"."COL13"=:B5 AND "BA2"."COL4"<>3 AND (:B6='ALL' AND :B7=0 AND "BA2"."COL6"=:B8 OR 
              "BA2"."COL2"=:B9 AND ("BA2"."COL6"=:B10 OR "BA2"."COL6"='ALL')) AND ("BA2"."COL2"<>:B11 OR 
              "BA2"."COL2"=0)))
   9 - access("PSCL"."COL2"="PCL"."COL2")
       filter("PSCL"."COL6"="BA"."COL6" OR "BA"."COL6"='ALL')
  10 - access("PP"."COL1"(+)="PCL"."COL1")
  12 - access("PCL"."COL1"="BA"."COL1")
       filter("PCL"."COL2"="BA"."COL2" OR "BA"."COL2"=0)
  15 - filter("PSCL"."COL4"<>3)
  16 - filter("BBA"."COL9"=617617)
  17 - access("BBA"."COL7"=:B1)
  18 - filter("BSA"."COL7"=:B1)
  19 - access("BSA"."COL8"=617617)
  20 - filter("BA2"."COL12"=:B1 AND "BA2"."COL13"=:B2 AND "BA2"."COL4"<>3)
  21 - access("BA2"."COL1"=:B1)
       filter((:B1='ALL' AND :B2=0 AND "BA2"."COL6"=:B3 OR "BA2"."COL2"=:B4 AND ("BA2"."COL6"=:B5 OR 
              "BA2"."COL6"='ALL')) AND ("BA2"."COL2"<>:B6 OR "BA2"."COL2"=0))
  24 - access("CVP"."COL2"=:B1)
  26 - access("CVP"."COL10"="CC"."COL10")
  29 - filter("SA"."COL14"=100805)
  30 - access("SA"."COL8"=617617)
  31 - filter("PCL"."COL14"=100805 AND ("SA"."COL2"="PCL"."COL2" OR "SA"."COL2"=0) AND 
              "PCL"."COL4"<>6)
  32 - access("SA"."COL1"="PCL"."COL1")
  34 - access("PP"."COL1"(+)="PCL"."COL1")
```

Comment: "I improved my SELECT by replacing LEFT JOINs and ORs with EXISTS:" apparently not!  I'm not sure if anyone will want to reverse engineer your rather obtuse query

Comment: Possibly worth mentioning that this is a follow-up to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/77280049/266304), though the query has got more complicated.

Comment: It would be hard to call this an *improvement*. Performance tuning is very time consuming task that generally require database access to try different approaches. The easiest entry point to identify slow places is SQL monitor report available in EM or via [DBMS_SQL_MONITOR.REPORT_SQL_MONITOR (<params>, type => 'ACTIVE')](https://docs.oracle.com/en/database/oracle/oracle-database/19/arpls/DBMS_SQL_MONITOR.html#GUID-04851EB0-32AB-424C-91A1-65AD9220A690). It will provide an overview of the execution flow, wait events, timelines etc to make deeper investigations more directed.

Comment: You probably need more parentheses. What you currently do is `WHERE ba.COL8 = 617617 OR EXISTS(SELECT 1 FROM T6 bba WHERE bba.COL7 = ba.COL7 AND bba.COL9 = 617617) OR (EXISTS(SELECT 1 FROM T7 bsa WHERE bsa.COL7 = ba.COL7 AND bsa.COL8 = 617617) AND ba.COL4 <> 3 AND...`. I.e. your main problem isn't performance.

Comment: @jarlh Thank you very much for your response. I think that parentheses are definitely needed there. I tried now with parentheses but unfortunately, still the same problem. It takes "forever" to execute this SELECT

Comment: You can also change `UNION` to `UNION ALL` if you are not expecting duplicates.

Comment: Try adding the `/*+ USE_CONCAT */` hint after the `SELECT` keyword at the top outer query and also in the `ba2` subquery. Check the plan then and see if it is able to transform the ORs into concatenated queries, thus eliminating the ORs within the plan. Index all your join columns. And learn the lesson that bad data modeling leads to these kinds of problems.

Comment: @PaulW Thank you very much for your response. I tried with /*+ USE_CONCAT */ but now it takes 2200 ms to execute instead of 700 ms.

Comment: It was a guess that would only work properly if you have all the right indexes in place, which is unlikely. 700ms??? You're complaining about 700ms for a query like that? I'd say that's fast enough. I'm certain it can be improved but with the complexity of that query and the difficulty of getting help from those who can't see your data or indexing setup, I'd take that to the bank and move on to the next task.

Comment: @PaulW Yes, I agree that 700 ms is not much for that complex query. I was assigned to the task of improving this query. Wasn't my decision. Fascinating is that if I leave only 1 condition inside (ba.COL8 = 617617 OR bsa.COL8 = 617617 OR bba.COL9 = 617617) and remove other 2 then it takes 10-20 ms to execute instead of 700 ms. Leave any one condition and remove any 2 other conditions. But if I leave all 3 then it takes 700 ms to execute. How can I transform this query to use UNION instead of LEFT JOINs and ORs?

Comment: You have too many OR conditions in your joins. If there was just one of these, it would be easy to write three SQLs each with a single column as the driving predicate and then UNION ALL them together. But you have least three places in the code where this is happening. The data model is completely wrong and needs overhauling to standard rules of normalization. Then you wouldn't many all these variable key columns and your SQL would be straight forward.

Comment: @DaniChe It's great that you added the SQL Monitor results for one of the queries, but you really need to post the results for BOTH versions of the queries.  And the report is most useful for the slow query, because then you can see precisely which operation is taking the most amount of time, and then only focus on that one small part. (Although it looks like you've already identified the section through trial and error. But comparing the estimated versus the actual row count may provide insight into how the different happens and what mistake the optimizer is making.)

Answer (score 4):

In [the answer to your previous question](https://stackoverflow.com/a/77280212/266304) the query was simpler and the entire `where` clause was:

```
WHERE  ba.COL8 = 617617
OR     EXISTS(SELECT 1 FROM T6 bba WHERE bba.COL7 = ba.COL7 AND bba.COL9 = 617617)
OR     EXISTS(SELECT 1 FROM T7 bsa WHERE bsa.COL7 = ba.COL7 AND bsa.COL8 = 617617)
```

You have now added more conditions:

```
WHERE ba.COL8 = 617617
        OR EXISTS(SELECT 1 FROM T6 bba WHERE bba.COL7 = ba.COL7 AND bba.COL9 = 617617)
        OR EXISTS(SELECT 1 FROM T7 bsa WHERE bsa.COL7 = ba.COL7 AND bsa.COL8 = 617617)
    AND ba.COL4 <> 3
    AND pcl.COL4 <> 3
    AND pscl.COL4 <> 3
    AND NOT EXISTS
...
```

You haven't done anything to modify the default [condition precedence](https://docs.oracle.com/en/database/oracle/oracle-database/19/sqlrf/About-SQL-Conditions.html#GUID-65B103FE-C00C-46A3-8173-A731DBF62C80). You may just need to add parentheses:

```
WHERE
    (
        ba.COL8 = 617617
        OR EXISTS(SELECT 1 FROM T6 bba WHERE bba.COL7 = ba.COL7 AND bba.COL9 = 617617)
        OR EXISTS(SELECT 1 FROM T7 bsa WHERE bsa.COL7 = ba.COL7 AND bsa.COL8 = 617617)
    )
    AND ba.COL4 <> 3
    AND pcl.COL4 <> 3
    AND pscl.COL4 <> 3
    AND NOT EXISTS
...
```

Untested of course as we don't have your tables or data, but it's a simple problem to resolve first. While it's primarily a logical problem - you will include data with matching T6 or T7 rows regardless of the other conditions - it seems likely to be causing at least some of the performance problem as well.

Comment: Thank you very much for your response. I think that parentheses are definitely needed there. I tried now with parentheses but unfortunately, still the same problem. It takes "forever" to execute this SELECT.